# ignore fields on update view

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a very large form that I have an update view for. The issue is when the users submits an update it says some fields are required such as author and post date. I don't want users to change these fields. The fields are manually rendered

How can I ignore these fields in the update view.

I have tried to set the requirements to false

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['author'].required = False
    self.fields['date_posted'].required = False
```

But this throws a `null value in column "author" of relation "blog_post" violates not-null constraint`

Alot of posts said to add `null=True` but these fields cannot be null

view:

```
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostFormUpdate
   
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user.id == post.author_id:
            return True
        return False
```

form:

```
class PostFormUpdate(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve it is just create a new Form to the edit action as following:

```
class PostFormUpdate2(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        exclude = ('author','date_posted')
```

Then you will not have that data in the form as following:

```
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostFormUpdate2
   
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user.id == post.author_id:
            return True
        return False
```

This is the idea, try to test it and if it gives you an error let me know in the comments.

Comment: `exclude` did the trick thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can set **blank=True** either in model class which will be implemented on all http methods or using the above technique you used

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['author'].blank = True
    self.fields['date_posted'].blank = True
```

blank=True means you are not requiring any values from forms for those fields...

Comment: still throws the form error that they are required

Comment: show me your models.py file or model class

Comment: try also with exclude=['',''] instead of fields='__all__' with null=True  and blank=True sepcified

Answer (score 0):

This makes it so the user cannot change the form field but it is still displayed

```
widgets = {
   'date_posted': forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}), }


def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['date_posted'].required = False
```